# What allows us to write $P(T_2 >t) = E[P(T_2 >t)| T_1] $

Tags: probability

I am currently working with a time process, $T_1, T_2, ..$.

I saw in an associated paper that  $P(T_2 >t) = E[P(T_2 >t)| T_1]$. I wasn't sure what property allowed me to do this as it appears that the expectation via the integral will always leave something left over. Is there a probabilistic property here that makes this statement valid? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any extra information?  By default I assume probabilities like "$P(T_2>t)$" are fixed (deterministic) numbers, unless there is any conditioning.  If so, then the equality is trivial!!  (Perhaps this trivial equality is a precursor to using some property of conditional expectation?)

Comment: Do you have difficulties with the generic identity $\mathbb{E}[h(T_2)]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[h(T_2)|T_1]$?

Comment: I suspect a typo, and the RHS should be $\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{P} (T_2 > t | T_1) ]$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean $E(P(T_2 > t | T_1))$ as mentioned by @P.Windridge. $P(T_2 > t | T_1)$ is a function of $T_1$ so:

\begin{align}
E(P(T_2 > t | T_1)) &= \int_0^\infty P(T_2 > t | T_1) f_{T_1}(x) dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty (\int_t^\infty f_{T_2 | T_1}(y) dy) f_{T_1}(x) dx \\
&= \int_t^\infty \int_0^\infty f_{T_2 | T_1}(y) f_{T_1}(x) dx dy \\
&= \int_t^\infty \int_0^\infty f_{T_1 , T_2}(x, y) dx dy \\
&= \int_t^\infty f_{T_2}(y) dy \\
&= P(T_2 > t)
\end{align}

Comment: Yup. This is a general property of conditional expectation, which @Xi'an commented on (take $h(x)= \mathbb{1}_{x > t}$).